# Laravel validation fix 422

Tags: laravel, validation

i am trying to create a private function which pre-pends a nullable tag onto certains fields for validation so i can set the boolean inside the function whenever i want certain fields to be null but for some reason i keep getting a 422 error when i try to test creating fields that are null.

Can anyone spot the reason? thanks.

```
class FilmController extends Controller
{

    protected $validation = [
        'name' => 'string',
        'description' => 'string',
        'film_url' => 'url'
    ];


    protected $null = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'film_url'
    ];


    public function filmCreate()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();

        $film = new Film()

        $this->filmValidate(true);

        return $film->toJson();
    }


    private function filmValidate($null = false): void
    {
        if ($null === true) {
            $this->nullFields();
        }

        Validator::make(
            $this->request->all(),
            $this->validation
        )->validate();
    }

    private function nullFields()
    {
        foreach ($this->null as $field) {
            if (array_key_exists($field, $this->validation)) {
                $this->validation[$field] = $this->validation[$field] . '|nullable|';
                return;
            }
            $this->validation[$field] = 'nullable';
        }
    }
```

Comment: why are you doing that... because nullable means that the field may be empty and it won't trigger the rest of validation rules.... you can put `nullable|...` there where you need it... or else explain more what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: basically i have another function which re-uses the same validation array which DONT require null fields so i only wanna add nullable fields onto this new function i am creating, i can create a new seperate validation array i just didnt know if this way would wok.